# Django TypeError: Model instances without primary key value are unhashable

Tags: python, django

I have my `models.py` as follows:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.TextField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.TextField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)


class Keyword(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.word
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='keywords_found', null=True, blank=True)
```

I encounter an error when I try to save the data like this:

```
Article.objects.create(date=publish_date, title=article.title, content=article.text, author=article.authors, url=url, keywords_found=keywords_found)
```

Here, `keywords_found` is a list of `Keyword` objects.

The error is:

```
TypeError: Model instances without primary key value are unhashable
```

Where am I going wrong?

Django version : 1.10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try saving it this way -

```
    art = Article.objects.create(date=publish_date,
                                title=article.title, 
                                content=article.text, 
                                author=article.authors,
                                url=url)

    Keyword.objects.create(word=keywords, article=art)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently facing a similar issue (still in the process of finding a solution), but I believe I can provide some insights that might be of help.

Within the Django framework, there exists a package named contenttypes under the django.contrib namespace, which could potentially be contributing to the problem you're encountering. You can find more information about this package here: [Django ContentTypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/). And it should be listed on settings.py INSTALLED_APPS

To delve into the issue, you could start by running the following SQL query on your database:

`SELECT * FROM django_content_type WHERE id IS NULL;`

Executing this query might reveal entries within the django_content_type table that lack an id value. Identifying these occurrences could potentially shed light on the underlying cause of the problem you're facing.