# Django Model as Python dictionary key

Tags: django, dictionary, django-models, primary-key, immutability

I need to build a dictionary which would have Django Models as keys but I get this error on a default made model:

> TypeError: Model instances without primary key value are unhashable

yet, Django documentation says that it takes care of building id as default primary key.

So why do I get this error?

Comment: Did you save your model instance ? The message is explicitely mentions an empty pk __value__ - and of course for auto (serial) pks, the value only exists once the record has been inserted in the table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django TypeError: Model instances without primary key value are unhashable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41532881/django-typeerror-model-instances-without-primary-key-value-are-unhashable)

Comment: @Bruno Thanks, my mistake ! Put as an answer, I will accept this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the error message explicitely mentions an empty pk **value**. IOW: 
you have to save the model instance first, serial (auto) id fields only get their values when the record is inserted in the table.